# Finding length of array and length of array with pointer pointing to it

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion

```
int a[17];
size_t n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
```

In C it is most common to find a length of an array like this and it is pretty clear. My question though is that the following wouldn't work:

```
int days[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *ptr = days;
size_t n = sizeof(ptr) / sizeof(int);
```

What I suppose is happening here is that ptr is just a normal 8-byte address pointing to the first element of the array, so it won't give us the real length of the array. But in the first example, sizeof(a), a is also just a pointer pointing to the first element of the array. So what is the difference here and why does one work but the other not?

Comment: Contrary to what some people will tell you, arrays are not pointers.

Comment: "...a is also just a pointer pointing to the first element of the array" no, no, no... `a` is **not** a pointer- it's an array. `ptr` is a pointer but `days` is an array

Comment: `a` is of type `int[17]`, which is statically known to the compiler; this type *decays* to `int*` in many contexts, but not all, and `sizeof` is one of the non-decaying contexts. The compiler in general can't know what `ptr` is pointing to. (In this example, an optimising compiler could probably infer that it points to length-5 array `days`, but imagine if `ptr` was changed around in various complicated ways between this initial assignment and the `sizeof ptr`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I suppose is happening here is that ptr is just a normal 8-byte
> address pointing to the first element of the array, so it won't give
> us the real length of the array

You are right.:)

> But in the first example, sizeof(a), a is also just a pointer pointing
> to the first element of the array. So what is the difference here and
> why does one work but the other not?

Array designators are converted to pointers to their first elements in expressions except using them as operands of the operator `sizeof` or the operator `&`.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So in this expression

```
sizeof(a)
```

the array `a` is not converted to a pointer.

If you will write for example

```
sizeof( a + 0 )
```

then you will get the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you have an array. sizeof(a) give the number of bytes required to store it.

In the second case, you have a pointer. sizeof(ptr) gives the number of bytes required to store the pointer (Depends on architecture, usually 4 or 8).

The compiler knows the array size but doesn't know how many elements are pointer by a pointer.